# wordpress get user nice name from database

Tags: wordpress

how i can get the users nice name in a function?
currently i got it with an avatar, but dont know hot to get the users nice name:

```
$table = $wpdb->prefix . "thumbsup_info";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT userid FROM $table WHERE postid = '$postid' LIMIT 10", ARRAY_A);
    $total_user = $wpdb->num_rows;
    for($i=0; $i <$total_user ; $i++)
        {   
            $userid.= get_avatar($result[$i]['userid'],100);


        }
    return $userid;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the user object with the following line of code:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $result[$i]['userid'] );
```

Then you can just access the property you need. To get the nicename for example you would use  `$user->data->user_nicename`